# ElasticSearch C# client (NEST): access nested aggregation with Spaces

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

Assuming my 2 values are "Red Square" and "Green circle",
when i run the aggregation using Elastic search i get 4 values instead of 2, space separated?
They are Red, Square, Green, circle.
Is there a way to get the 2 original values.

The code is below:

```
 var result = this.client.Search<MyClass>(s => s
            .Size(int.MaxValue)
            .Aggregations(a => a
            .Terms("field1", t => t.Field(k => k.MyField))
            )
            );


        var agBucket = (Bucket)result.Aggregations["field1"];

        var myAgg = result.Aggs.Terms("field1");
        IList<KeyItem> list = myAgg.Items;

        foreach (KeyItem i in list)
        {
            string data = i.Key;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your mapping, you need to set the `field1` string as `not_analyzed`, like this:

```
{
    "your_type": {
        "properties": {
            "field1": {
                 "type": "string",
                 "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also make `field1` a [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html) and make it both `analyzed` and `not_analyzed` to get the best of both worlds (i.e. text matching on the analyzed field + aggregation on the exact value of the `not_analyzed` raw sub-field).

```
{
    "your_type": {
        "properties": {
            "field1": {
                 "type": "string",
                 "fields": {
                     "raw": {
                         "type": "string",
                         "index": "not_analyzed"
                     }
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you choose this second option, you'll need to run your aggregation on `field1.raw` instead of `field1`.

Comment: .NET code ..var result = this.client.Map<ClaimForm>(m => m
                 .Properties(props => props
                    .MultiField(s => s
                        .Name(p => p.Plan)
                        .Fields(pprops => pprops
                                    .String(ps => ps.Name(p => p.Plan).Index(FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed))
                                    .String(ps => ps.Name("original").Index(FieldIndexOption.Analyzed))
                            )
                         )
                     )
                 );

Comment: Is there a way to get the counts of the items aggregated? like 3 "Red Square" 4 "Green circle"